# Passing javascript array values to link and retrieve it using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference: Why does the PHP code in my Javascript not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-code-in-my-javascript-not-work)

The output always `bool(false)` even I already check some check boxes, I don't know what is wrong.

So far here's what I've tried

Here is my code:

```
    <a onclick="href='wp-content/themes/twentyelevenchild/addmarked.php?asin=<?php echo serialize('+asinValues+')?>'" class="addmarkeditems fancybox.ajax">Save Test 2</a>
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var asinValues = $('input[name=checkboxlist]:checked').map(function(){
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
</script>
```

in my `addmarked.php`

```
<?php 
var_dump(unserialize($_GET['asin']));
?>
```

Screenshot of my firebug:

[image]

Comment: Please read the answer linked above. You can't do it like that, your php code will always run before any js.

Comment: @bfavaretto, thanks! ill read this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a quick working example of what you might be looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/ithcy/X3Ecx/2/

Your `addmarked.php` should be able to use `explode(",", $_GET["asin"])` or similar to do something with the values of all the checkboxes that were checked.

Comment: Won't work anyway, you can't serialize a js variable with php.

Comment: I know... I misread the post. I had deleted this answer, and I undeleted it too soon :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you added the missing echo:

```
<?php echo serialize('+asinValues+')?>
```

This totally does not do what you think it does. You cannot mix PHP and JS like that, because PHP is executed on the server first and if it happens to generate JavaScript, this will be executed on the client as generated.

So, what does PHP do here? Serializing a string with plus signs and letters: `'+asinValues+'`. Serialized it looks like that: `s:12:"+asinValues+";`

So what you have as HTML/JS is:

```
<a onclick="href='wp-content/themes/twentyelevenchild/addmarked.php?asin=s:12:"+asinValues+";'" class="addmarkeditems fancybox.ajax">Save Test 2</a>
```

Since there is no JS counterpart to PHP's unserialize, you will need another way to serialize. JSON would be a good idea:

**JavaScript**

```
'...?asin=' + JSON.stringify(asinValues)
```

**PHP**

```
json_decode($_GET['asin'])
```